# For-loop lost inputs in a mulit-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays. One with a string of names. The other, a multi-dimensional array, with an associated list of hours in three columns representing a day each.

I have attempted to match the two arrays so that I can display the name with the correct total pay. However, I suspect the input is not inserted into the array with hour[x][y]. Hence, not stored and I cannot display the total again.

```
 public class NameList
 {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String[] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
            int[][] hour = new int[10][3];
            String input;

                Integer x = null, y = null, z, total = 0, pay= 0;
                boolean cancel = false;
                for (int index = 0; index < name.length; index++) // First array - String names.
                {
                    for (x = 0; x <= hour.length; x++) // Second array - name name row.
                    {
                       for (y = 0; y < hour[x].length; y++) // Second array - name working hours column.
                       {
                            z = y + 1;
                            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter " + name[index] + "’s day " + z + " hours: " );
                            pay = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            hour[x][y] = pay;
                            total += hour[x][y];
                       }
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name[index] + " total sum of hours is: " + total);
                       total = 0;
                       break;
                    }
                }
                cancel = true;
        }
```

}

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking, but why have a loop over x and then break unconditionally? Why not just remove the loop and replace x with 0?

Comment: Declare x, y etc as primitive `int` instead of object `Integer`. You are doing arithmetic with them: the implicit autoboxing and unboxing here is way less efficient than primitive arithmetic. You don't need to declare x and y until the for loop guards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 for loops and because of `break` you are replacing value of 1st row only for hours. Remove inner for loop of x.

```
String[] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
int[][] hour = new int[10][3];
String input;

Integer y = null, z, total = 0, pay= 0;
boolean cancel = false;
for (int index = 0; index < name.length; index++) // First array - String names.
{
   for (y = 0; y < hour[index].length; y++) // Second array - name working hours column.
   {
        z = y + 1;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter " + name[index] + "’s day " + z + " hours: " );
        pay = Integer.parseInt(input);
        hour[index][y] = pay;
        total += hour[index][y];
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name[index] + " total sum of hours is: " + total);
   total = 0;
}
/*for (int x = 0; x < hour.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(name[x] + " : " + Arrays.toString(hour[x]));
}*/
cancel = true;
```

Comment: Stephen Bendl highlighted the same. Thanks!

Comment: @ rlee, @StephenBendl answered before me, so you should accept his answer. And you can vote up other useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you've nested three for loops, when I believe you should only need 2. Since the array of names and the array of hours is presumably aligned so that name[3] is "D" and hour[3][day] is how many hours worker D worked on a given day, you should only need a total of two for loops, one that will serve as your index for both arrays name and the first dimension of hour, and the second to index the day.

Additionally you can declare variables inside for statements, i.e.

```
for(int index = 0 ; index < name.length ; index++)
```

edit: I see you used this exact line in your program... is there any reason why you don't this syntax for the other two loops?

Comment: I suspected as much (that the 3 loops would fail). So I could presumably have these two loops?
   [for (int index = 0; index < name.length; index++)
       for (y = 0; y < hour[x].length; y++)]

Comment: I think two loops is really your only reasonable option. Think about what adding the third loop does to the program: for each name, loop over every single person's number of hours for each day. Doesn't really make much sense that way. In the future try using your IDE's debugging feature to follow your program's flow. You may find that it does things you don't always expect.